# Do something when window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code below to pen a window.. is it possible do to an ajax call if the window opens?

```
window.open("http://www.google.com");
```

For example when the window opens to do the call bellow:

```
var signalz = '1';
var dataString = 'signalz='+ signalz;

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "checker.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html) {   
if(html == 'done')
{

}
else 
{

}

}            
});
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible, did you try it ?

Comment: `if(window.open('http://google.com')){console.log('opened')} else {console.log('did not open')}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Solve came from user @aperture.. many thanks

if(window.open('http://google.com')){console.log('opened')} else {console.log('did not open')}